# Change GRS to LRS Backup Job

Tags: azure

I am looking for a way to change my Recovery Service backup type from Geo storage type to Local storage type.

I am hoping to change this without deleting all my backups.

Comment: I found this question that has some insight: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32015469/change-azure-backup-vault-redundancy)

Comment: This gives more info about different data replication modes .  As per the documentation under FAQs 3rd one it is mentioned that  "  If you change from GRS to LRS, there is no additional cost, but your data will be deleted from the secondary location."  Check with mssupport to make sure.    https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-redundancy

Comment: Thank you @Baskar, however that is talking about a storage account. I am dealing with the Backup Recovery Service so I am coming to the conclusion that I cannot change the redundancy after the job has been created.